# How to verify that template class is derived from a given class at compilation time?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, compiler-errors

I wonder, whether there is any elegant way (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532281/how-to-test-whether-class-b-is-derived-from-class-a/5902112#5902112)) for checking that template argument is derived from a given class?
In general:

```
template<class A, class B>
class MyClass
{
    // shold give the compilation error if B is not derived from A
    // but should work if B inherits from A as private
}
```

the solution provided in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532281/how-to-test-whether-class-b-is-derived-from-class-a/5902112#5902112) works only when B inherits from A as public:

```
class B: public A
```

however, I would rather not have such constraint:

```
class A{};
class B : public A{};
class C : private A{};
class D;
MyClass<A,B> // works now
MyClass<A,C> // should be OK
MyClass<A,D> // only here I need a compile error
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheriting privately from anything is an implementation detail.

During refactoring and code analysis I would be much happier if such detection would not be possible for functionality outside...

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like I said here:
[C++: specifying a base class for a template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888099/c-specifying-a-base-class-for-a-template-parameter/5892246#5892246)
in a static assertion (either C++0x or BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT)

```
template<class A, class B> 
class MyClass 
{ 
  static_assert( boost::is_base_of<A,B>::value );
}
```